# LookupError: No plugin named 'GremlinPlugin'

Tags: python, neo4j, keyerror

neo4j version 2.3.1, py2neo version 2.0.8, jdk 1.8, python 3.4. The Gremlin service was successfully installed. However, when running the project, it still shows that the plug-in cannot be found:

[image]

I tried to install the Gremlin service again, but it still didn't work. Is there any way to solve the error?